# Microsoft Graph mangles SharePoint list number column values

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a SharePoint Online list containing a number column with the following values:

- 90038946
- 90000624
- 90000627
- 235712345

When I use the Microsoft Graph API the values coming back are mangled:

- 90038940
- 90000620
- 90000620
- 235712352

This happens both using the [MS Graph dotnet sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) as well as the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explore) so it seems to be a feature of the MS Graph API Service.

The REST URI I'm using in Graph Explorer (where OrgUnitCode is the number column) is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SharePointTenant>,<SiteCollectionId>,<SiteId>/lists/<ListId>/items?$expand=fields($select%3DTitle,Code,Region,OrgUnitCode)
```

RESULT:

```
"fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"<GUID REMOVED>,1\"",
                "Title": "<REMOVED>",
                "Code": "<REMOVED>",
                "Region": "<REMOVED>",
                "OrgUnitCode@odata.type": "#Single",
                "OrgUnitCode": 90038940
            }
```

The SharePoint REST API returns the values without mangling the values:

```
https://<SharePointTenant>/sites/<SiteCollectionName>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<ListName>')/items
```

RESULT:

```
...<d:OrgUnitCode m:type="Edm.Double">90038946</d:OrgUnitCode>...
```

How do I turn off the mangling feature in Microsoft Graph so I can retrieve the actual values?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a service bug for the SharePoint Graph API.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/321#issuecomment-446754950

> This is a confirmed service bug and has been escalated to the proper team.